# Notepad 2 insert character after regular expression search

Tags: regex, notepad2

I am having an issue with trying to figure out how to insert some text after I perform a regex search. I know there is a replace function, but I am not looking for that option, just inserting. The text editor I am using is Notepad2, but I am willing to try this in other text editors.

Here is the example that I have.

```
TEST|Test2|Test3|Test4
```

This is what I am looking for

```
Test|Test2|PrefixTest3|Test4
```

Notice that I am trying to insert the the phrase "Prefix" after the 2nd pipe and leave everything else alone.

I can successfully query the result by using this regex:

```
^[^|]*\|[^|]*|
```

But then I do not know how I can retain everything prior and after the search point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `\K` inorder to discard the previously matched characters.

```
^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|\K
```

Then replace the match with the string `prefix`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/12)

Answer (score 0):

You may easily do that in **Notepad2** using the *regex*-based *Replace* feature.

**Find**:       `^\([^|]*|[^|]*|\)`
**Replace**: `\1Prefix`

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line (Notepad2 never overflows line boundaries!)
- `\([^|]*|[^|]*|\)` - Capturing group 1 matching a sequence of:

  - `[^|]*` - zero or more chars other than `|`
  - `|` - a *literal* (yes, no escaping is necessary, both escaped and unescaped `|` match a literal `|`) pipe symbol
  - `[^|]*|` - see above, gets to the second `|`.

The replacement contains a `\1` backreference that inserts what was captured with the capturing group 1.
[image]

NOTE that Notepad2 regex engine is very limited. Here is what the [Notepad2 documentation says](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/doc/notepad2-FAQs.html#q27):

> Notepad2 supports only a limited subset of regular expressions, as provided by built-in engine of the Scintilla source code editing component. The advantage is that it has a very small footprint. There's currently no plans to integrate a more advanced regular expressions engine, but this may be an option for future development.
>
> *Note: Regular expression search is limited to single lines, only.*

Also, you may refer to the inline comments inside [Scintilla *RESearch.cxx* file](https://github.com/LuaDist/scintilla/blob/2b9d6ca86328da98fbffcec5c93590b1ddfbb5c2/src/RESearch.cxx#L53) describing the supported syntax. Bear in mind that the regex type used in the Notepad2 S&R tool is that of *POSIX* and not all of the described Scintilla regex features will work in the tool.

Note that Notepad2 does not seem to support alternation and limiting quantifiers (similar to Lua patterns), but `\w` matches Unicode letters together with ASCII ones. Sadly, I could not make `?` quantifier work.

Answer (score -1):

```
^([^|]*\|[^|]*\|)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1prefix`.See demo.Just capture the first group and then use it for replace.The first group can be accessed by `$1`.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/11

Comment: Care to explain how and why this would work, if it does?

Comment: @Shmiddty does that answer your question?

Comment: Here is a reference on the site's standards for answering questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Shmiddty care to explain what exactly do you think is missing